# Can I Split a cell on Jasper Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to create this table ( [Link to my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqWOg.png) ) on Jasper Report but I'm having some trouble to generate it on my Jaspersoft Studio. I'm using the object called "Table". Now my questions are:

Can I split a single cell in two or more cells? If it will possible, how can I do this?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you split cells? You have six cells in the details area: "aventi diritto" and "consumati" per different meals.

So there are six cells that would correspond to six database fields.

What you have above ("Colazione", "Pranzo", "Cena", "Medie") are just fixed texts that are not related to the six-column-details area.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so I have to do the same reasoning for this
schema? Link to image -> https://ibb.co/yyMtM8G

Comment: @FedericoLuzi Yes, same reasoning.